# Best way to animate a circle moving around a screen in Qt?

Tags: user-interface, qt, animation

If I wanted to, using Qt, simply have some circles move around in a white box, or a graphic, what would be the best method of this?

Would I need to draw white/the graphic behind where the circle moved from every time?  Is there a simple way of accomplishing this in Qt?

Answer (score 4):

1. Create QGraphicsView object to your widget and added a QGraphicsScene to view.
2. Add a QGraphicsEllipseItem to scene
3. Use QPropertyAnimation to change the "pos" property of the ellipse item.

If you need more advanced features, you can build your own animation class on QPropertyAnimation.

enjoy it:)

Update: You can read [Qt's Next Generation UI](http://doc.trolltech.com/qq/32/qq32-next-gen-uis.html) for more information.

Comment: Hi, using property animation how can i animate the circle like literally drawing the circle. I am designing a timer, so I need to show this visually. Can you show me how to do it?

Comment: not use Qt for long time. and not sure how the latest Qt handle it. have you checked the doc of QPropertyAnimation  here? http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qpropertyanimation.html

Comment: Oh ok thanks. What I am doing now is, in paint(), I update using drawArc() API to show as the circle being rotated (Actually, it's a timer). Is it possible to do this with property animation? Because in property animation, as far as I have seen, the position of the object itself is changed and the animation is set with a duration, which won't suit my needs.

Answer (score 0):

Subclass a QWidget.  Start a timerEvent() to animate the positions of the circles, then call update() at the end to schedule a repaint of the widget. Override the widget's paintEvent() - in there you draw your background and circles, using a QPainter object. The Qt Assistant has examples of how to use QPainter.

Qt also has a new animation framework that may facilitate something like this, but I have not looked into it.

Comment: So we do have to redraw the background every time?

Comment: Yeah, pretty sure you do, but if you needed the efficiency there's probably some work-around. I do a lot of custom drawing in paintEvent and it's always pretty quick.

Comment: With Qt Graphics Framework, you don't need to handle these kind of low level operations. See my reply below.

Comment: Cool, thanks Mason. Good to know. I haven't gotten into that part of the framework.